# Python 3 urllib HTTP Error 403: FORBIDDEN with localhost using params

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, urllib

I have been trying to make a POST request in this way:

```
def simular(request):
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode({'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'bacon': 0})
    data = data.encode('utf-8')
    request = urllib.request.Request("http://localhost:8000/aguaman/actualizar/")
    # adding charset parameter to the Content-Type header.
    request.add_header("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8")
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(request, data)
    return HttpResponse("se está simulando la cosa para que funcione: " + str(data))
```

But I am getting the error 403 forbidden

Then I try to do the same request but I am not using the params so it would be somethink like this:

```
def simular(request):
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode({'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'bacon': 0})
    data = data.encode('utf-8')
    request = urllib.request.Request("http://localhost:8000/aguaman/actualizar/")
    # adding charset parameter to the Content-Type header.
    request.add_header("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8")
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    return HttpResponse("se está simulando la cosa para que funcione: " + str(data))
```

And it works, So I would like to know if something is missing, or maybe I cannot use urllib in the way I am doing for local files.

after reading in several places, I found that changing header can help, I already did that and tried to use:

```
hdr = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, data, hdr)
```

But is useless, same result. does anyone can explain the reason? thanks

Comment: What HTTP server are you running on port `8000` of your local host?

Comment: I am pretty new using python, and to run the server I am using `python3 manage.py runserver`, should I use another one?

Comment: So the next Q is of course, what's the `WSGI_APPLICATION` in your settings, and, what's the code for that application.  The 403, after all, **is** being returned by your server, so without seeing all details of that server (and maybe the logs it writes with all the details of why it's returning 403, to exactly what request, and so forth) it's impossible to help you.

Comment: Thanks @AlexMartelli, My entire project name is aguamanserver so checking the settings I can read `WSGI_APPLICATION = 'aguamanserver.wsgi.application'`, what do you mean when you say "what is the code?", I understand the 403 is been returned by the server, but I think there is something wrong in the local server config, so the problem won't be in the python code, right ? the question would be, is there any special config to create a local server to run this kind of scripts?

Comment: The problem starts on the server side, requiring authentication for posts to that URL -- in Django, that requirement can be imposed in a myriad ways (settings, middleware, routing, your application code, no doubt even more -- Django's grown frighteningly complex, which is why these days I personally stick with lighter-weight, less-rich frameworks such as flask).  If you want to allow anonymous, unauthorized posts to that URL, it's your server (settings onwards) that you must debug.  If you **don't** want anonymous passerbys to post, then the 403 is right!-)

Answer (score 0):

After making a lot of different changes I started using @csrf_exempt before the views definition, so at the end I finished with these code

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def simular(request):
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode({'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'bacon': 0})
    data = data.encode('utf-8')
    request = urllib.request.Request("http://localhost:8000/aguaman/actualizar/")
    # adding charset parameter to the Content-Type header.
    request.add_header("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8")
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(request, data)
    return HttpResponse("se está simulando la cosa para que funcione: " + str(data))`
```

doing this, I was disabling the django security request for this view, I tried to test and the error continued, so I shutted down the server, and turned it on again, and starts working.

Maybe there is something in the server that checks those kind of variables in the app before start running them, so now I can continue working. thanks !